# Websocket 1006 only on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, browser-cache, ratchet

I'm working on a websocket, but for some reason only on chrome the 1006 error pops up.
I've read the definition of it on [ietf.org](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-7.4.1).
It says that the problems lies locally in the browser and not with the server, thus the only usefull answer I could find (about chrome's header being bigger than the max acceptable header of the server). 
I use [ratchet](http://socketo.me/) as websocket backend so even if that was the problem I couldn't fix, because (at least) I could not find a parameter where you could edit that maximum.

According to [this](http://websocketstest.com/) website, my google chrome's socket should work.
It works on firefox and safari, making me belief it's a chrome issue, but I can't find any starting points.

The "Connection start" of the chrome network dev tool says "Stalled 13.8 days", but clearing my cache in chrome's settings does not help.
According to the [demo of ratchet](http://socketo.me/demo) it shouldn't say "13.8 days", but rather stay at ~250ms.
There is nothing usefull in the error event object and close event object, except for the 1006 error code the close event gives.

I've also tried the websocket on another computer that never opened the site before and I still got the 1006 error.

I'm connection with the websocket like this:

```
let websocket = new WebSocket('wss://example.com:8080');
```

I've also tried port `50437`

The SSL certificates works on the other webbrowsers and a postman tot the websocket results in a 426 (Upgrade Required) as it should. (TLS handshake was successful and trusted)

What should I try to fix this.
Tell me if you need more information.